# Can I use std::bind to convert a pointer to member function into a pointer to function?

Tags: c++, bind, member-functions

I want to pass a member function as a call-back. The call back is a basic function pointer.

So I have something like:

h file:

```
void (*pRequestFunc) (int someint) = 0;
void RegisterRequestCallBack(void (*requestFunc) (int someint))
{
    pRequestFunc = requestFunc;
}

class A
{
    void callBack(int someint);
}
```

Cpp File:

```
RegisterRequestCallBack(&A::callBack); // This does not work.
```

**Note** I have tried to extract this example from my larger example and cut out all the other stuff - so it might not be perfect.

The problem, as far as I understand, is that member function pointers really (under the hood) have an extra parameter (and instance - i.e. `this`) and are not compatible with normal function pointers.

the `RegisterRequestCallBack()` is in reality not my code - and so I can't change that.

So I read that boost::bind can do what I need - and I am hoping c++11 std::bind can do the same - but I could not figure out how to use it to effectively get a standard function pointer from a member function pointer...

I was going for something like:

`std::bind(&A::callBack)` ... that is about as far as I got, my understanding of the examples online is poor :(

Comment: Yeah - it's not always obvious ... `std::bind(&A::fn, instanceOfA (can be pointer), argsTofn)`

Comment: @UKMonkey but that won't produce a function pointer. In fact, it is impossible to store that into a function pointer, because it needs bound arguments.

Comment: @Quentin You're right - I seem to automatically convert some lines in my head; like function pointer to std::function.

Comment: AFAIK this cannot be done.

Comment: maybe, if the A::callBack is static

Comment: Well, you could create a static function; that has access to the std::function that it then needs to call; but really why not just use a `std::function`?

Comment: @Quentin bugger! - lol, thanks all for comments/answers. It does not look hopeful... It seems like it should be possible / something people have to deal with all the time.... but I guess in my case I am not allowed to change the `RegisterRequestCallBack()` function... don't really want to go static either....hmm... I maybe have to re-design something...  or maybe Lambda's to the rescue? (somehow!)

Comment: @RickyL. away from my dev pc at the moment, but I presume that `auto` could be re-written as `void (*) (int someint)`? - as in I know the type I want... I sort of get lambdas, but not quite this one - can you explain a little?

Comment: @code_fodder the issue is that you want to store what function to call *and* on which object to call it. A function pointer can only store the former, so you need either an erased type (such as `std::function`) instead of the pointer, or an additional pointer to the parameter (typical C APIs take in a `void *` for that purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NathanOliver's comment is correct, and your suspicion is mostly correct. Exactly how pointers to member functions work is not specified, but including `this` as a hidden argument *mostly* works. You just need a bit of extra work for inheritance and pointers to `virtual` functions (yes, you can take their address too).

Now, often callbacks include a `void*` parameter under your control, which you can use to pass a `A*`. In those cases, you can write a wrapper (`static`) function that casts the `void*` back to `A*` and does the actual call to `&A::callback`.

That's not the case here. Registration takes a single function, without data. To get this to work in real-life situations, you have to resort to drastic solutions - not portable C++. One such method is to dynamically generate assembly (!). You create - at runtime - the compiled equivalent of

```
void __trampoline_0x018810000 (int i)
{
   A* __this = reinterpret_cast<A*>(0x018810000);
   __this->callback(i);
}
```

As you can see, you have to generate one trampoline for every `A*` value, and managing lifetimes of these is a major pain.

Comment: Not the answer I want (obviously)...  but that's good information either way +1 - don't think i'll attempt your trampoline, I can't even understand it :p .. I'll wait just a bit longer in case someone has a great idea

Comment: After a a few years! and more experience I have come across this trampoline pattern a few times and even had to use it once or twice myself (less so with modern c++). But now I can see this as the accepted answer (sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to bind to a member function you need to do:

```
std::function<void(int)> function = std::bind(&A::foo, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Or in your case:

```
RegisterRequestCallBack(std::bind(&A::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

But in my opinion the clearest way to achieve this is to use lambda functions. Here you have an example to for doing something similar that could inspire you:

```
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class TaskManager {
    public:
        using task_t = std::function<void()>;

        void run();
        void addTask(task_t task);

    private:
        std::vector<task_t> _tasks;
};

void TaskManager::run() {
    for (auto& task : _tasks) {
        task();
    }
}

void TaskManager::addTask(task_t task) {
    _tasks.push_back(task);
}

class Example {
    public:
        Example(){
            taskManager.addTask([this]() {
                task1();
            });
            taskManager.addTask([this,a=int(4)](){
                task2(a);
            });
        }

    TaskManager taskManager;

    private:
        void task1(){ std::cout << "task1!\n"; }
        void task2(int a){ std::cout << "task2 says: " << a << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Example example;
    example.taskManager.run();
}
```

which outputs:

```
task1!
task2 says: 4
```

Comment: You're changing the interface.  The OP wants to pass the function to a function that takes a regular function pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was updating the answer to cover his case too

Comment: You're not covering the case though.  `RegisterRequestCallBack(std::bind(&A::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));` won't compile.

Comment: Nope.  It returns something but it can't be a function pointer as it needs to store the object to call the member function on.